# Android App Links not checked by default in Android

Tags: android, react-native, mobile, deep-linking

I encountered an issue related to my deep links.

I've developed a React Native app and configured everything to have my Android verified links. However, when I download my app (regardless of whether I download the production version from Google Play or compile a new dev version using the emulator), none of the verified links are checked by default. They are available, and I can manually check them, but by default, they remain unchecked.

I've tested manually checking them, and they work as expected.

Additionally, I've used the validator tool, and everything seems to be fine.

I suspect it might be a bug because in the Google Play Console > Deep links, I see a message saying "4 links not working." However, when I try to filter them by clicking on "filter web links," or I click on a link in the "Web link sections," each of them displays the message "No issues found."

Any idea what might be going on or how to fix it? Thanks!